# Socket IO - Threads/Posts and Updating the user view [Advice]

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm currently putting together a Node JS forum-like web-app, where users can post content and reply. In order for users to see the replies, they need to click the initiating post, and the replies load.

When a reply is added, I trigger a socket event to update everyone's view.

Two things need to happen:

1) Everyone who is looking at the same replies as the ones I have replied to need to see my new content.

2) Everyone else needs to see that the post I have replied to has a new reply.

The way I achieve this is on successful insertion of the data to the database, a helper is called to generate a partial view, of the replies, and then pushed back to the user to update (jQuery handles the rest).

I'm unsure of the best approach to take though regarding the data object that is submitted with the Socket.IO event.

There are two possible solutions I can think of.

1) When a user clicks a post (and the replies load) - they join a "room" with the ID of the post they have clicked. On new replies, everyone in that room will receive the update, and people who *are not* in the room will receive another object stating 'x' post has had a reply. When a user closes the replies (to look at something else) - it will emit a socket event from the browser to leave the room they were looking at, and then join the new room.

2) When someone replies to a thread, the data object is sent out with the update object to all audiences, regardless of whether they are looking at a reply or not, and jQuery will do some logic to determine whose view it should update.

When the app is built, I expect there to be be up to 1000 users on there at any one point - so I am want to do this in the cleanest way possible.

Thanks

Comment: The first solution seems to be cleaner and less data heavy, as it would only send the type of update required for each user (the users that don't need the updated information won't get it, resulting in less traffic being sent between the server and clients).

Comment: Thanks @Blubberguy22 - I opted to go for the first solution and it seems to be working out OK so far :)

Comment: Good; post another question if you run into problems trying that and let me know so I can try to help if you need it. Good luck!